# Can a server using http1.1 protocol be able to serve a request coming from browser using http2 protocol

Tags: node.js, http, http2

For example I have a node server which uses the built-in module "http" (which is http1.1 version I assume). So will it be able to serve any XHR request from browser with http2 protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Browsers negotiate HTTP/2 as part of the HTTPS setup (since browsers only support HTTP/2 over HTTPS). If HTTP/2 is not supported by both sides it will just use HTTP/1.1

Thanks one of the great things about HTTP/2 and why it’s made such headway - the ability to (almost!) seamlessly roll it out to the web without breaking existing sites/servers/browsers.